# SQL Server SELECT column not in Group By clause?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

As you can see my query, this is the working one

```
SELECT m.MerchandiseId, m.MerchandiseName, createdAt =  MAX(i.CreatedAt) FROM Inbox i
INNER JOIN [User] u
ON i.FromUserId = u.UserId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Merchandise m
ON u.MerchandiseId = m.MerchandiseId  OR i.ToMerchantId = m.MerchandiseId
WHERE i.ToCompanyId = 10 OR i.FromCompanyId = 10
GROUP BY m.MerchandiseId, m.MerchandiseName
```

[image: This is the result after query the above statement]

What if i want to SELECT one more field as i.InboxMessage with the Last record of each group?

```
SELECT m.MerchandiseId, m.MerchandiseName, i.InboxMessage, createdAt =  MAX(i.CreatedAt) FROM Inbox i
INNER JOIN [User] u
ON i.FromUserId = u.UserId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Merchandise m
ON u.MerchandiseId = m.MerchandiseId  OR i.ToMerchantId = m.MerchandiseId
WHERE i.ToCompanyId = 10 OR i.FromCompanyId = 10
GROUP BY m.MerchandiseId, m.MerchandiseName
```

I've tried some ways that I found in stackoverflow, but I still not manage to do it. Thousand of thanks if anyone would help on this.

Comment: What criteria defines "the last record of each group"?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ MerchandiseId and MerchandiseName

Answer (score -1):

FYI, I just solve my issue by using the subquery

```
SELECT m.MerchandiseId, m.MerchandiseName, (SELECT TOP 1 e.InboxMessage FROM Inbox e WHERE (e.ToMerchantId = m.MerchandiseId AND e.FromCompanyId = 10) OR (ToCompanyId = 10 AND FromMerchantId = m.MerchandiseId) ORDER BY e.CreatedBy ASC) AS InboxMessage, createdAt =  MAX(i.CreatedAt) FROM Inbox i
INNER JOIN [User] u
ON i.FromUserId = u.UserId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Merchandise m
ON u.MerchandiseId = m.MerchandiseId  OR i.ToMerchantId = m.MerchandiseId
WHERE i.ToCompanyId = 10 OR i.FromCompanyId = 10
GROUP BY m.MerchandiseId, m.MerchandiseName
```

Here's the code that I worked on

Comment: The main query and the subquery have different joining conditions. Which looks like the wrong thing to do.